# Google Cloud Pubsub authentication error from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

We're having trouble publishing messages to a Google Cloud PubSub topic on Google AppEngine. Using the Application Default credentials works perfect locally. But once it's deployed on Google AppEngine it gives the following error:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/our-project-id/topics/our-topic:publish?alt=json returned "The request cannot be identified with a project. Please pass a valid API key with the request.">
```

I would assume that it's will use the service account of app engine to access the PubSub API. Here is the code we used to create the credentials.

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
if credentials.create_scoped_required():
   credentials = credentials.create_scoped(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub'])

http = httplib2.Http()
credentials.authorize(http)
pubsub_service = build('pubsub', 'v1', http=http)
```

The error is thrown when publishing the actual message to PubSub.

```
pubsub_service.projects().topics().publish(topic="projects/out-project-id/topics/out-topic", body = { 'messages' : [ { 'data': base64.b64encode(request.get_data()) }]}).execute()
```

Not that the same flow works doing API call's to "**BigQuery**", so it's not a general Google API problem. It seems to be specific to PubSub...

Comment: Is the project where the target topic exists the same as the project you deployed the app?

Comment: yes it is, we only have one cloud project. We even tried to explicitly give the "appspot" service account Editor right on the topic.

Comment: Is it possible for you to invite me (tmatsuo@google.com) as an editor to investigate?

Comment: I've mailed you direct.

Comment: Ok, seems like your service account is not associated with any project ids, which seems like a problem on our side. Let me investigate more and I will let you know.

Comment: It should be fixed now. Please try again and let me know if it works now. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rare case of the service account without project id embedded in it. We fixed your service account and you should be good to go now. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: The project is quite old, but we never used app engine since recently.