# Error while register device for App Engine GCM

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, google-cloud-pubsub

have a problem while using Google Cloud Messaging in android. I tried to run the sample in developer.google.com, I did all the steps and I also installed Google Play Services. But when I run the project in order to get an InstanceID token, I get an error: "An error occurred while either fetching the instanceID token, sending the fetched token to the server or subscribing to the PubSub topic. Please try running the sample again "

Comment: what sample are you trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

@Waran-, based on the error you received you are having problem getting the instanceID. Have you check the [pre-requisites using Pub/sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/prereqs)?

May be you are encountering in the [Google PubSub authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582434/google-cloud-pubsub-authentication-error-from-app-engine?rq=1)
or you were unable to configure [Google Cloud PubSub push Subscriber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800269/unable-to-configure-google-cloud-pub-sub-push-subscriber?rq=1).

Also here is a guide to check if you have to [implement GCM in android](http://rmarcejaeger.com/2015/09/18/tutorial-how-to-implement-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-part-1-client-app/) and to try a [App Engine Backend with Google Cloud Messaging" Template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints)